# Use java to draw a progress bar in the console

Tags: java, console

When install some packages from command line, sometimes you can see a progress bar displayed in the console. And it update in the same line based on the progress.

How to clear the screen when update?

Comment: And what's your concrete question? Your posted answer `2J` do clear the whole screen.

Comment: @SubOptimal I mean use java to implement a similar progress bar in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using Mac with Java 8. This demo works for me. I didn't test it on Windows :(
>
> **NOTE:** if you run the code in your IDE(eg. IntelliJ, Eclipse, etc.), it may doesn't work. The right place to test it is in the terminal.

### Steps to run

1. open the folder where this code located in your terminal;
2. compile the code `javac Demo.java`
3. run it `java Demo`

   ```
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

   public class Demo {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

       int i = 0;
       int j;

       while (i <= 100) {
         System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
         j = 0;
         for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
           System.out.print('■');
         }
         for (; j <= 100; j++) System.out.print(' ');
         System.out.print(i + "%");
         TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
         i += 2;
       }
     }
   }
   ```

PS.

In the code above, you might be confused with this line: `System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");`

- 'H' means move to top of the screen
- '2J' means "clear entire screen"

Here is the detailed [explanation](https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/1uuvqo/clear_terminal_screen_linux/)